# Python syntax for logical operator "and"

Tags: python, syntax

Creating a simple login system which reads from a text file and compares the entered details. I'm really struggling to find help with the syntax for the 'and' operator in this.

Here is my code in Python for creating this system. I'm struggling to see why it won't work.

[Screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSOeE.png)

If I comment out the 'and' statement it still says user not found.

Comment: post code not images

Comment: the `and` should be on the previous line without the colon, it reads like English you know...

Comment: remove colon (:) from the line above where you are getting the error.

Comment: roshan I wanted to show the error message as well as my code. This killed 2 birds with 1 stone. I didn't know you would have to click on the image to see when I posted my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `and` should be on the same line. Your if statement finished after the `:`, so all conditions should be written between the `if` and the `:`

It should look like this:

```
if (loginname in credentials) and (credentials[username] == password):
    print("\n Login successful \n")
else:
    print("\n User doesn't exist or wrong password \n")
```

Read more about the python operators [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm), including the logic `and`

Comment: Why add unnecessary parentheses? And you still need a colon!

Comment: @Chris_Rands I wrote the code quickly copying it from his image, he didn't post the code on his question. And the parentheses are there to help him understand better how to seperate the different conditions with the `and`

Comment: The parentheses were very helpful Adam. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The "and" syntax:

```
if loginname in credentials and credentials[username] == password:
    print("...")
```

By the way what is "loginname" in your code? I guess it is "username" ?

Comment: Thanks. This has helped me no end

Comment: If you found what you are looking for, please mark the question as answered.